# How to turn a 200~Khz AC voltage into a proportional DC voltage that does not exceed 3.3V

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, high-frequency, induction

now, I have an induction heater, which runs at 200 Khz, and near the coil of the induction heater is another coil, now, if they coil is near the IH's output, currents will be induced into it, yes?

Now, if we have a 3.3 volt ADC, and we connect the output of that coil to the ADC, and say, the voltage in the coil can get pretttty high, even in the thousands of volts, if it gets near enough to the coil of the induction heater, how can I make such a variable high-frequency voltage take form of a 3.3 volt signal proportional to the voltage on the coil? I have thought of using a transformer, which would have a specific turns ratio, but, if the voltage gets high enough on the coil, then the transformer will output more than 3.3, frying our ADC, therefore some sort of protection is required.

What is an elegant solution to this? Also, I need to be able to calculate the actual voltage on the coil.

The ADC is 12-bit.

Now, to make it clear, I only want to find the voltage in the coil, if you have an IC or something I can connect via SPI/I2C and measure it directly, I don't mind that, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Enough with "now" all over the place!  Show some respect by not dumping slop on those you seek a favor from.  Proofread what you write, and actually *think* about what it will be like for others to read it, and what kind of impression they form of you as a result.  My impression is definitely not positive.  I quit at the third "now" and will move on to more deserving questions.  *Screw this*

Comment: Surely the best way to get the voltage on the coil is .. measure the voltage on the coil? But what for?

Comment: @pjc50 by measuring voltage and current one can accurately find the tuning point where maximum power is transferred (Power Factor=1). Frequency changes with different loads, shapes and temperatures. Where the primary is part of an oscillator tank circuit this is of little concern other than grossly incorrect loads,  but with digital drive, a feedback loop is advantageous or essential.

Comment: The wording of your question is quite confusing, and doesn't really provide much info. It would be easier to answer if you simply stated a) what your set up looks like, hopefully including a nice schematic, b) what issues you have and c) what exactly your question(s) is/are. Also including a datasheet for things like your ADC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Why measure voltage or current at the primary of an IH?**

```
a) You need to study the voltage and current academically.
```

You will get a reading from the coil you propose, but it will not be accurate. Different loads, load positions and temperatures will influence the readings due to mutual inductance changes and Curie temperature effects.

A Separate VT, CT, shunt, hall sensor or other instrument is advised in this situation

```
b) You wish to tune the heater frequency.
```

This is probably the most practically beneficial application

The absolute measure is not required, you need to pick up the phase change and tune for 90 degree phase shift.

[Richie Burnett](http://www.richieburnett.co.uk/indheat.html) explains it nicely with bode plots and practical advice and [a great discussion](http://4hv.org/e107_plugins/forum/forum_viewtopic.php?33509.0). [Here's another](http://www.rmcybernetics.com/projects/DIY_Devices/diy-induction-heater.htm) site. Google "Induction Heater control Bode Plot" for some academic articles. [This](http://cdn.intechweb.org/pdfs/13440.pdf) one looked good when I  scanned it - kept it to read later as it has the maths.

Your method will work for current measurements.

For best results, try to keep the measurement coil away from the influence of the load.

---

**Voltage Measurements**

The voltage of the primary is relatively easy to measure using a VT or potential divider, some signal conditioning and protection.

Provide protection to both rails using Schottky diodes in a bridge.

Protect the rail with a TVS or Zener in case your power supply cannot absorb the voltage spikes being fed into the rail.

Search your favorite supplier for an Instrumentation Amplifier that works at 3.3V and gives rail to rail outputs- there are many to choose from.

**Current Measurements**

In order to measure the current, treat the solution you describe as an air cored CT that measures amps rather than volts. Provide a shunt to contain the voltages and quantify the current.

The phase relationship between current and voltage is probably the most interesting parameter you want to measure and control.

[Burnett](http://www.richieburnett.co.uk/indheat.html) describes the entire process and provides practical advice needed to implement the instrumentation and control you require.

I've considered, but never tried or seen anyone using a Hall sensor. There are many to choose between.

They measure the magnetic field directly from which the current can be deduced.

There are two varieties

```
- sensors with built in op amps
- switches with built in comparators
```

Comment: Tesla coils are tank-tuned to produce big voltages - don't confuse CTs with tesla coils. Despite a lot of crap on the internet saying CTs can produce thousands of volts it is very unlikely that they actually do because of core saturation when the burden is removed.

Comment: Remember, every capacitor has its own tiny inductor, likewise there is capacitance between the windings. The energy is lost through a combination of internal sparking, capacitance, corona discharge and breakdown arcing. I've experienced high voltages under the right conditions - yes saturation happens but your 3V micro is toast much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

> if they coil is near the IH's output, currents will be induced into
>   it, yes?

No, a voltage will be induced in it.

> Now, if we have a 3.3 volt ADC, and we connect the output of that coil
>   to the ADC

Very bad idea - try using a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitors and then a regulator before connecting it to the ADC.

> say, the voltage in the coil can get pretttty high, even in the
>   thousands of volts, if it gets near enough to the coil of the
>   induction heater

This is unlikely unless that coil has been tuned like a tank circuit with a parallel capacitor.

> I have thought of using a transformer, which would have a specific
>   turns ratio, but, if the voltage gets high enough on the coil, then
>   the transformer will output more than 3.3, frying our ADC, therefore
>   some sort of protection is required.

You need what I specified above.

> What is an elegant solution to this? Also, I need to be able to
>   calculate the actual voltage on the coil.

The details that are needed to produce any solution are not clear. You have coil A and, coil B may be close (but how close?) and it may have tuning capacitors (my thoughts). Distances unspecified, coil dimensions unknown. Superfluous information like "12 bit ADC". More (and relevant) info needed to give good answers on this part but, also, don't expect elegance and don't expect a solution on a plate. Expect advice and criticism.

Comment: all the maths I ever did described magnetic circuits in terms of amps, not volts. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @ChrisR well, a transformer secondary when open circuit doesn't have an induced current but it does have an induced voltage. Any currents produced are a by-product of the induced voltage and the coil's self-impedance into whatever load is connected. I presume you refer to my opening answer?

Comment: >Regulator
That won't produce a proportional voltage, will it?
>Unless the coil is tuned like a tank circuit
The IH is an LCLR coil, which does have a lot of resonant rise on its LC tank, on the orders of thousands of volts and hundreds of amps.

Comment: I think you need to better explain what you are trying to do and with what specific coils connected to what power sources.

Answer (score 0):

Why not rectify the 200KHz with some fast HV     diodes .Your AC coil voltage     waveform will be a reasonable sinewave so the relationships between peak RMS and average are predictable and well documented.Your voltage will be way too high but your current needs are low so a peak rectifier will work.Just use a resistive divider with nice quality resisters rated for the expected DC volts .Experiment using your DVM to get your resister divide ratio right for the ADC .